# Tensorflow restore fails to find tensors when closing and reopening a session

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a model that looks something like this:

```
# Training the model
relevant_tensors = build_model(params)
with tf.Sesion() as sess:
    # do steps for model training...
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, "mymodel.ckpt")

# Prediction
relevant_tensors = build_model(params)  # params here the same as previously, so we build the same model
with tf.Session() as sess:              # New session
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.load(sess, "mymodel.ckpt")
```

I get a Not Found error when I try to load the checkpoint in that order. I'm building the graph in the same way, using the function build_model, and I've verified that the parameters are identical on both calls.

If I comment out the training step, the prediction step will load the model from the previous run just fine. But when I try to do both steps, I get a failure on loading the checkpoint.

Anyone see the logic here?

Comment: Can u copy paste failure stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are building the model twice in the same (default) `tf.Graph`, so the nodes created on the second call to `build_model()` will get different names that don't line up with the names of the variables in the checkpoint.

A simple solution is to create different `tf.Graph` objects for training and prediction, for example:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():  # One graph for training the model...
    relevant_tensors = build_model(params)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # do steps for model training...
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, "mymodel.ckpt")

with tf.Graph().as_default():  # Another graph for prediction....
    relevant_tensors = build_model(params) 
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, "mymodel.ckpt")
```

An alternative approach would be to change `build_model()` so that it can build a single graph for training and prediction, and then you could use the same graph and session for both tasks.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense now. I naively imagined that closing the session cleared context like this, but now that I think about it makes sense that it wouldn't.